# Conditional shifting pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to conditional shift pandas column, would want to shift all columns with i > 6 below is what I am doing and it is not working

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating data for 'i' and 'price' columns
n = 10  # Number of entries
i_values = list(range(1, n+1))
price_values = [10.99, 19.99, 5.99, 8.49, 12.99, 15.99, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99]

# Creating DataFrame
data = {'i': i_values,
        'price': price_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['price_new'] = df.loc[df.i>6, 'price'].shift(-3)
```

Expected output:

```
n = 10  # Number of entries
i_values = list(range(1, n+1))
price_values = [10.99, 19.99, 5.99, 8.49, 12.99, 15.99, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99]
new_price_values = [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]

# Creating DataFrame
data = {'i': i_values,
        'price': price_values,
        'new_price': new_price_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Hello there, care or some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the shift, then select the cells you wish to keep. It looks like you're attempting to do it all at once and simply getting the indices wrong in the process.

**What you seek as a one-liner**

```
shift_from = 6
shift_by = -3

df['price_new'] = df.loc[df.i>(shift_from+shift_by),'price'].shift(shift_by)
```

This produces exactly your expected output.

**Decomposed in 2 steps for clarity**

With dispensable intermediate column.

*1) Apply shift*

```
df['price_shift'] = df['price'].shift(shift_by)
df
    i   price   price_shift
0   1   10.99   8.49
1   2   19.99   12.99
2   3   5.99    15.99
3   4   8.49    9.99
4   5   12.99   14.99
5   6   15.99   6.99
6   7   9.99    11.99
7   8   14.99   NaN
8   9   6.99    NaN
9   10  11.99   NaN
```

*2) Select cells*

```
df['price_new'] = df.loc[df.i>(shift_from+shift_by), 'price_shift']
df
    i  price  price_shift  price_new
0   1  10.99         8.49        NaN
1   2  19.99        12.99        NaN
2   3   5.99        15.99        NaN
3   4   8.49         9.99       9.99
4   5  12.99        14.99      14.99
5   6  15.99         6.99       6.99
6   7   9.99        11.99      11.99
7   8  14.99          NaN        NaN
8   9   6.99          NaN        NaN
9  10  11.99          NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
df['new_price'] = df['price'].where(df.index >= 6, np.NaN).shift(-3)
```

The problem with `df.loc[df.i>6, 'price'].shift(-3)` is that it's selecting the last four rows (the ones where index is greater than 6:

```
>>> df.loc[df.i>6, 'price']
6     9.99
7    14.99
8     6.99
9    11.99
```

and then it's shifting those:

```
>>> df.loc[df.i>6, 'price'].shift(-3)
6    11.99
7      NaN
8      NaN
9      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating data for 'i' and 'price' columns
n = 10  # Number of entries
i_values = list(range(1, n+1))
price_values = [10.99, 19.99, 5.99, 8.49, 12.99, 15.99, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99]

# Creating DataFrame
data = {'i': i_values,
        'price': price_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['price_new'] = df.loc[df.i>6, 'price']
df['price_new'] = df['price_new'].shift(-3)
```

So, first create new column (price_new), and then apply shift.