# Conditional shifting of pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I correctly conditionally shift a column in a pandas DataFrame? I want to shift all values in a specific column where the corresponding 'i' value is greater than 6. The code I am using currently does not produce the desired result.

Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating data for 'i' and 'price' columns
n = 10  # Number of entries
i_values = list(range(1, n+1))
price_values = [10.99, 19.99, 5.99, 8.49, 12.99, 15.99, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99]

# Creating DataFrame
data = {'i': i_values,
        'price': price_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['price_new'] = df.loc[df.i>6, 'price'].shift(-3)
```

The expected output should be:

```
n = 10  # Number of entries
i_values = list(range(1, n+1))
price_values = [10.99, 19.99, 5.99, 8.49, 12.99, 15.99, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99]
new_price_values = [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]

# Creating DataFrame
data = {'i': i_values,
        'price': price_values,
        'new_price': new_price_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional shifting pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76710147/conditional-shifting-pandas-column)

Comment: exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76710147/12846804, down to the digit

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be filter the values where `i > 6`, assign to new column and shift it:

```py
df['new_price_2'] = np.where(df.i > 6, df['price'], np.nan)
df['new_price_2'] = df['new_price_2'].shift(-3)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    i  price  new_price  new_price_2
0   1  10.99        NaN          NaN
1   2  19.99        NaN          NaN
2   3   5.99        NaN          NaN
3   4   8.49       9.99         9.99
4   5  12.99      14.99        14.99
5   6  15.99       6.99         6.99
6   7   9.99      11.99        11.99
7   8  14.99        NaN          NaN
8   9   6.99        NaN          NaN
9  10  11.99        NaN          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly conditionally shift a column in a pandas DataFrame, you can use the np.where function along with boolean indexing to achieve the desired result. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating data for 'i' and 'price' columns
n = 10  # Number of entries
i_values = list(range(1, n+1))
price_values = [10.99, 19.99, 5.99, 8.49, 12.99, 15.99, 9.99, 14.99, 6.99, 11.99]

# Creating DataFrame
data = {'i': i_values,
        'price': price_values}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Conditionally shift the 'price' column where 'i' > 6
df['new_price'] = np.where(df['i'] > 6, df['price'].shift(-3), np.nan)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    i  price  new_price
0   1  10.99        NaN
1   2  19.99        NaN
2   3   5.99        NaN
3   4   8.49       9.99
4   5  12.99      14.99
5   6  15.99       6.99
6   7   9.99      11.99
7   8  14.99        NaN
8   9   6.99        NaN
9  10  11.99        NaN
```